# Using C# and mschart control how do I rename X Axis values on a stacked column chart?

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

Using C# and mschart control how do I rename X Axis values on a stacked column chart?

Below is the portion of my code that displays only the first value on the x axis.  If i try to include a line similar to `chart2.Series[0].Points[x].AxisLabel = array[x].name;` in the other if statements, it gives me an error.

```
if (array[x].name == "Preci_4") 
{
    if (array[x].Digital_Location == "DIO0") 
    {
        chart2.Series[0].Points.AddXY(0, array[x].count_1s * 6);
        chart2.Series[0].Points[x].AxisLabel = array[x].name;
    }
    else 
    {
        chart2.Series[1].Points.AddXY(0, array[x].count_1s * 6);
    }
}
else 
{
    if (array[x].Digital_Location == "DIO0") 
    {
        chart2.Series[0].Points.AddXY(1, array[x].count_1s * 6);
    }
    else 
    {
        chart2.Series[1].Points.AddXY(1, array[x].count_1s * 6);
        // chart2.Series[1].Points[x].AxisLabel = array[x].name;
    }
}
```

Here is my result:

[image]

Comment: Please take a moment to edit your question and align that code properly.

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem?